# How do I take unlimited sys.argv[] arguments?

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, command-line-interface, argv

To elaborate, I am interested in learning how to code out in python a `sys.argv[]` function that allows the user to supply as many arguments as the user wants. I am unsure on if there is a better way to do this or if it can be done at all.

The point to this is to develop a similarity tool between text docs of various size and quantity. the use case in this situation takes as little as `argv[1]` and as many as argv[unlimited].

Any input, sources, or advice is welcome.

Comment: Not sure I get the question.  `sys.argv` is a `list`.  It can have as many elements as you want (barring limits placed by the OS, memory limits in hardware, etc...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sys.argv` is just a regular Python list, so you can just ask `len(sys.argv)` for example, or you can just enumerate the contents directly (using a `for ... in` loop) as with any other iterable.

Note that `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the program, so you need to skip the first item.  (It then follows that `(len(sys.argv) - 1)` is the number of arguments supplied by the caller.)

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    print arg
```

Example invocation:

```
$ python test.py a b c
a
b
c
```

In your case you would replace `print arg` with whatever processing you wanted to do on the argument.

This will work up to any operating-system-imposed limits.  (Some OSes limit the number of arguments you can pass to a program.  For example, on Linux you can see these limits with `xargs --show-limits`.)

Comment: i didn't realize it was set up like a normal list so if i can iterate over the list then i can dynamically expand the list. for some reason I had a preconceived idea that it was called one at a time.  i feel like a derp. i blame it on monday.

Comment: thanks for the clarification on this issue i was having.

Comment: @castaway2000 That's exactly what that syntax means, yes. It's a [list slice](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists). I'm not sure what you mean by *"if i can iterate over the list then i can dynamically expand the list."* You don't create or expand this list; Python creates it before your script is executed.

Comment: i feel like an idiot. what I mean is I can use the for loop to assign/use the indexes as if they were variables and use the list with a comparison algorithm and pass it to my parsing code. so i dont even need to assign them to hard coded variables. --my brain is toast right now, i blame it on monday-- thanks for your help. to gave you the answer cause you spelled it out the best for me.